# get the x and y cordinates of textpath on path displaced with startOffset

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Is there way to get the x and y coordinates of the text which is aligned using the startOffset on path.

http://jsfiddle.net/pkolanda/zxgtwhpp/1/

```
 destinationPortText.enter().append("text")
       .attr("class", "label")
       .attr("dy", 4)
       .attr("font-size", 10)
       .attr("fill", "black")
       .append("textPath")
       .attr("class", "textPath")
       .attr("startOffset","75%")
       .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return '#' + d.source.id + '-' + d.p1 + '-'  + d.target.id + '-' +d.p2;})
```

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#__svg__SVGTextContentElement__getStartPositionOfChar

Comment: Really this is useful... thanks a lot.. i will start the investigation on using it.